# Scala code is compiling but returning a run time error.

Tags: scala, runtime, traits

The below code is compiling fine but returning an error at runtime. I think there is something that I'm getting wrong about Traits in Scala. The problem manifests when the addItem function is called in the application. I'm just curious as to what I'm doing wrong. The error message follows the code.

```
trait Heap {
  def addItem(item: Int): Heap
}

case class heap(n: Int,
                l: Heap,
                r: Heap ) extends Heap {
  val node: Int = n
  val left: Heap = l
  val right: Heap = r

  def addItem(item: Int): Heap = {
    if (item < node) {
      new heap(item,r.addItem(node),l)
    } else {
      new heap(node,l,r.addItem(node))
    }
  }
}

case class leaf extends Heap {
  def addItem(item: Int): Heap = {
    new heap(item,new leaf,new leaf)
  }
} 




object test extends Application {
  var a = new leaf
  a.addItem(5);
}


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Heap (wrong name: heap)
```

Comment: Were you compiling this on Windows?

Comment: Do you have the default Mac OS installation option for case insensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that something is wrong about my naming convention for Heap, the trait, and heap, the class. I think the JVM is compiling the names together in such a way that the trait Heap is taking the same name as the class heap. Changing the name from heap to h solved problem.